# How to calculate $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\ 1.5 e^{-ik\pi \ t} \ \ dt, \, k \in \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: integration, exponential-function

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\ 1.5 e^{-ik\pi\ t} \ \ dt, \, k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: This is the same as $1.5e^{-jk\pi}\int t dt$ as you can pull out any constants.

Comment: Is $t$ really not part of the exponent?

Comment: Yea t is a part of the exponent I have edited it now @DavidSchneider-Joseph  .

Comment: @Kaynex $t$ suppose to be a part of the exponent. My bad sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation is straightforward:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac34 e^{-ik\pi t}\ \mathsf {dt} &= \left.\frac{3i}{4k\pi}e^{-ik\pi t}\right|_0^1\\
&=\frac{3i}{4k\pi}(e^{-ik\pi}-1)\\
&=\frac3{4k\pi}((-1)^k-1)i.
\end{align}

Comment: Note: I write $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$ and not $j$ because this is math.stackexchange and not electronics.stackexchange :)

Comment: It is okay I got it. But actually I don't understand what is meant by $A$ in the first line

Comment: @HossamHoussien It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! it really helped :) @Math1000